# GLSurfaceView display abnormal with many small cells after relaunching the Android Camera

Tags: android, camera, glsurfaceview

Using the `GLSurfaceView` to display camera preview data, i got the abnormal preview(as the following screenshot) if i do the following operations:

1. launch app and open camera
2. press the HOME key
3. re-launch app and open camera

[image]

Comment: Hi @fadden , Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution as following:

In the `CameraGLRender`, which implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, do something in the `onSurfaceChanged`

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0, width, 0, height, -10f, 10f);
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    // ...
}
```

It works fine.